# SQL Server Report Filter Expressions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

So I have two datasets called Employee and EmployeeData. Employee is the main dataset that is used by the report and I want to add a filter to it. The filter parameter is created as EmployeeID. Employee has columns Name, Department, Job, etc. EmployeeData has columns Name, EmployeeID, Address.

I'm trying to filter using EmployeeID on Employee so I need to do some sort of join with EmployeeData using Name as the key. This would be easy in SQL but since I'm new to SSRS, I don't know what the syntax of the expression would look like here.

Thanks

Comment: What if you have two employees with the same name? Why can't you add the EmployeeID to the Employee dataset - isn't it a relational data source? Are Employee and EmployeeData connected to different databases?

Comment: It's just the way the infrastructure is set up I believe. EmployeeData is generated from a view and Employee is from a DataService that I don't know much about.

Answer (score 1):

Create another parameter `@employeename` and set it's default value to the employee name from the employeename dataset, then use that parameter to filter the Employee dataset based on the like operator and the name field.
SSRS is very sensitive to parameter order, so you may need to delete and recreate them in the correct order.